# App crashes when I navigate to another frame

Tags: c#, xaml

When I click, the second page is loaded, but the application crashes with `System.NullReferenceException`:

```
private async void Forecast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await
    CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
            CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
            () => {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(Forecast), null);
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

A `NullReferenceException` occurs when trying to access a member of an object which is `null`.

This is likely happening within your code.  Reproduce the error while running your application in Debug mode, and view the call stack/current point of execution when you encounter the exception.  It should then be clear to you in which statement your code is trying to access a member of a `null` object.